# Capitalize first letter in sentence in MS Word after the fact

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors, text-editing

Ive pasted in text from another text editor into Word, then turned on Autocorrect. It doesn't correct after the fact as I can see. Is there a shortcut I could do to fix it?

Comment: Unless there is an option to do so (I haven't used recent versions of Word), auto-correct isn't applied retrospectively: if it were, then any misapplied corrections which you have undone would be reapplied, so it applies only to new text. Try selecting the pasted text, cutting it and repasting with auto-correct enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Select the text and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

On a Mac you may need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> [instead](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-capitalization-or-case-of-text-1d86cf80-fbef-4380-8d6f-59a6b77db749)

This will cycle between first letter capitalised, all words capitalised, all *first letters* capitalised and all words lower case.

Or just click on the single word you want to have a capital and press the above to only work on that word.

Comment: do you know what the Mac equivalent would be? Its not working on my macbook.

Comment: @user718229 apparently it should be `fn+ SHIFT + F3 `